# Panel bug when TAB key press

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel on which I paint and when I press Tab Key everything disappears.

I have a textBox too and I tried to see if I press Tab key by calling PreviewKeyDown event and check there and repaint everything but it doesn't work.

What did I do wrong?

This is how I paint on that panel:

```
private void PuneFundal(Graphics g)
{
 g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(150, 124, 92));
}

    private void DeseneazaLinie(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2)
{
     Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
     g.DrawLine(p, p1, p2);
}

private void TrasareLinii(Graphics g)
{
     for (int i = 6, k = 0; k < 20; i += 16, k++)
         DeseneazaLinie(g, new Point(5, i), new Point(309, i));
     for (int i = 6, k = 0; k < 20; i += 16, k++)
         DeseneazaLinie(g, new Point(i, 5), new Point(i, 309));
}

private void Start_game()
{
     Graphics g = m_off_joc_nou_panel.CreateGraphics();
     PuneFundal(g);
     TrasareLinii(g);
}
```

***My solutin:***

```
using System.Drawing; //for Graphics and Images and the tool to paint

 public Form1()
{
    Image img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}

private void Start_game()
{
    Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    // here you paint what you whant

    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a code sample where it fails?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy that is the point I don't know why it erase everything. It erase everything even it in previous tabPage I press TAB key.

Comment: You might want to see if you can create a small sample app that reproduces this problem. If it doesn't happen, slowly work towards the code you have to see what introduces the issue.

Comment: @JeffBridgman the problem appear when I created the Graphics, so I decided to change the panel with a pictureBox and I created an Graphics from that image and every time I change the picture I used this code: `Image img = pictureBox1.Image; Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);               //here I change the picture                                     pictureBox1.Image = img;` (sorry for this look but I dont know to arange this code)

Comment: Where does that code fit in? Could you please add it to the question? Do you have the `using()` statement on `g` or `img`? Or call `Dispose()` somewhere?

Comment: Only ever use CreateGraphics() if you constantly paint at a high rate, the kind of painting that's appropriate in a game loop.  Other usage requires painting with the Paint event instead.

Comment: @ThomasW. I added the code how you asked.

Comment: @HansPassant I was creating a game for my highschool certificate, every time I whas pressing left, right, up and down I had to move a piece